# Shower cuts off 2-3 minutes

Tags: water-pressure

We built our home about 34 years ago and we have a private well. For the last several years, we’ve experienced our water will shut off for 2-3 minutes in the entire home, then return to full flow. My husband has changed the pressure switch and things would work fine for several months. Here lately we’ve experienced more frequent issues with the water shutting off and changing the pressure switch only helps for a week and back to shutting off. Now it’s happening several times daily. We get plenty of rain, so I don’t think we have the issue of needing to dig a new well.

Comment: Is the well pump running at that point? Is there pressure in the tank at that point?

Comment: What are the characteristics of the well? What is the flow rate? If it's a low producing well, or production dropped for some reason, the pump might be "sucking air" or if you have a system that shuts off the pump when the level gets too low that might be the cause. Older system use electrodes on wires going down the well casing to detect the water level, newer systems use an electrical current monitor and cuts power to the pump when current level drops.   This works because the pump will draw less power when "sucking air" rather than water.

Comment: Ran out of space in comments...continuing: It's unlikely the pressure switch was the issue. They are pretty reliable and if they break, they break!  No coming back off and on.   If you don't have a water level monitoring system in the well or a current monitoring system controlling the pump, it's probably the well isn't producing as much as it was.  This happens, esp. if other wells in the area were recently drilled, lowering the water table aquifer. Some areas have aquifers, others have underground "rivers".  You probably need a "pump guy" to check things out.

Comment: Geeze, I just keep going here:  What type of pump? Jet pump? submersible? Well depth? Static water level in well when not pumping? Most counties and/or states have records on wells, you might consult them to learn more about your well.

Comment: I'd agree - continually replacing the same part only to have the same symptoms return is a pretty good indicator that the part you're replacing isn't the issue.